# django filebrowser extensions problem

Tags: python, django, uploadify, django-filebrowser

I've set django filebrowser's debug to True and wrote the extension restrictions in the model.

pdf = FileBrowseField("PDF", max_length=200, directory="documents/", extensions=['.pdf', '.doc', '.txt'], format='Document', blank=True, null=True)

In django admin it shows correctly with debug info.
Directory documents/
Extensions ['.pdf', '.doc', '.txt']
Format Document

But when I call the filebrowser, it allows all file extensions to be uploaded.

How can I restrict filebrowser to upload only certain filetypes that I want?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

In filebrowser/fb_seettings define them as a dictionary called EXTENSIONS.

```
EXTENSIONS = {
    'Folder':[''],
    'Image':['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif','.png','.tif','.tiff'],
    'Zip':['.zip', '.rar'],
    'Video':['.mov','.wmv','.mpeg','.mpg','.avi','.rm'],
    'Document':['.pdf','.doc','.rtf','.txt','.xls','.csv'],
    'Sound':['.mp3','.mp4','.wav','.aiff','.midi'],
    'Code':['.html','.py','.js','.css']
}
```

Edit: If you want if in your FileBrowserField:

```
pdf = FileBrowseField("PDF", max_length=200, initial_directory="documents/", extensions_allowed={'Documents':['.pdf', '.doc', '.txt']}, format="Documents", blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: I already have that defined by default in the settings.py file.
The problem is overriding the default settings with those defined in the model filebrowsefield arguments.

Comment: Can you please tell which version of filebrowser you're using, and where you found it?

My version, which i checked out from svn trunk doesn't have extensions_allowed or initial_directory as variables.

Just extensions and directory.